# I need to upgrade scrapy 12 to scrapy 16, on ubuntu.. can you help me with the command

Tags: python, ubuntu, scrapy

I need to upgrade [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) 12 to scrapy 16, on ubuntu. can you help me with the command

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can do:

```
git clone https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy.git
cd scrapy
python setup.py
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried:

```
pip install --upgrade Scrapy      # if it's the latest version
```

or:

```
pip install Scrapy==0.16     # specific version
```

To avoid further problems, take a look at examples in the [pip documentation](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#examples).